# phpunit cannot find Class, PHP Fatal error

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4, classnotfoundexception

1. I get phpunit and install it as [this link](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) using the simplest way for test purposes.

   I just download the phpunit.phar file, chmod & rename & move to /usr/local/bin Then, I run phpunit --version, its ok.

   `PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann`
2. I write a simple test

   ```
   public function testSomething(){

      $this -> assertTrue(true) 
   }
   ```

   Then I go into the source file folder, `phpunit --colors Test`

   It works. So, I decide write a complex demo.
3. My project folder structure is like this.

   ```
   Project Name
      --> app
          --> api
          --> tests
   ```

   Now I write a simple class in  `app/api/FlyApi.php`

   ```
   <?php

    class FlyApi {

        public function makeFly(){
           //do something else
        }
    }
   ```

   Then I write another test class for FlyApi.php

   ```
   <?php

    class FlyApiTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

        public function testFly(){
           //new a FlyApi
           $flyApi = new FlyApi();

           //do something
        }
    }
   ```

   At this line `$flyApi = new FlyApi()` I got the error.

   PHP Fatal error: Class 'FlyApi' not found in /home/kevin/Workspace/fly/app/api/FlyApi.php on line 23

   Yes, this line `$flyApi = new FlyApi()`

Comment: Technically you're just missing to require the class definition of `FlyApi` because PHPUnit does not do some magic auto-loading for you. It's your job to provide the unit under test before testing it (or if the class yet does not exist: it's perfectly okay that the test fails with a crash of Phpunit as the test has been written  before the code as in TDD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't load the definition of your `FlyApi` class.

This solution is Laravel specific:

You should be extending `TestCase` rather than `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your `/api/` folder into your `ClassLoader` at `app\start\global.php`.

You will find this section:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    ...
    app_path().'/api/
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Laravel's [phpunit.xml](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/phpunit.xml#L4) file? It includes Laravel's (and Composer's) `autoload.php` file which lets you use all your autoloaded classes within it.

Finally, what's the whole error? It should (hopefully) tell you what class it's trying to load (which will give you clues if the namespace is wrong or something).