# PHPUnit cannot find source code

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, php-include

I have a PHP project, with the following project structure.

```
php_test_app
    src
        Vegetable.php
    tests
        StackTest.php
        VegetableTest.php
```

The code of these files is shown below. I use PDT and PTI in Eclipse. PHPUnit in Eclipse recognizes that `VegetableTest.php` belongs to `Vegetable.php`, because you can toggle between them using the toggle button.

I first try to run the test code by selecting the tests directory in the PHP Explorer and click `Run Selected PHPUnit Test`. It runs both tests, both the `VegetableTest` fails with the following trace: `Fatal error: Class 'Vegetable' not found in /Users/erwin/Documents/workspace/php_test_app/tests/VegetableTest.php on line 8`. A similar issue was posted here: [phpunit cannot find Class, PHP Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942487/phpunit-cannot-find-class-php-fatal-error).

Indeed, I haven't included my source code yet, so now I uncomment the include in `VegetableTest.php`, shown below. If I now try to run the tests in the same way, PHPUnit does not recognize any test code! Even the `StackTest`, which is unaltered, is not recognized.

1. How should I make the include such that the unit tests are
   recognized?
2. Do I need to specify the full path, or just the name of
   the file in which the class is defined?

Changing the include statement also doesn't work; I have tried the following.

```
include 'Vegetable.php';
include 'src/Vegetable.php';
include '../src/Vegetable.php';
```

**Vegetable.php**

```
<?php

// base class with member properties and methods
class Vegetable {

    var $edible;
    var $color;

    function Vegetable($edible, $color="green")
    {
        $this->edible = $edible;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    function is_edible()
    {
        return $this->edible;
    }

    function what_color()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

} // end of class Vegetable

// extends the base class
class Spinach extends Vegetable {

    var $cooked = false;

    function Spinach()
    {
        $this->Vegetable(true, "green");
    }

    function cook_it()
    {
        $this->cooked = true;
    }

    function is_cooked()
    {
        return $this->cooked;
    }

} // end of class Spinach
```

**StackTest.php**

```
<?php
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
?>
```

**VegetableTest.php**

```
<?php
// require_once ('../src/Vegetable.php');

class VegetableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_constructor_two_arguments()
    {
        $tomato = new Vegetable($edible=True, $color="red");

        $r = $tomato.is_edible();
        $this->assertTrue($r);

        $r = $tomato.what_color();
        $e = "red";
        $this->assertEqual($r, $e);
    }
}

class SpinachTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_constructor_two_arguments()
    {
        $spinach = new Spinach($edible=True);

        $r = $spinach.is_edible();
        $this->assertTrue($r);

        $r = $spinach.what_color();
        $e = "green";
        $this->assertEqual($r, $e);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have nothing to contribute with I just wanted to say I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

`phpunit --bootstrap src/Vegetable.php tests` instructs PHPUnit to load `src/Vegetable.php` before running the tests found in `tests`.

Note that `--bootstrap` should be used with an autoloader script, for instance one generated by [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) or [PHPAB](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload/).

Also have a look at the [Getting Started](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html) section on PHPUnit's website.

Comment: Thanks. I now included the bootstrap file, and it seems to recognize at least the existence of the class. However, now it does not recognize the first function in the class: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_edible() in /Users/erwin/Documents/workspace/php_test_app/tests/VegetableTest.php on line 9`

Comment: It also still leaves open the question why no tests are recognized if you manually include the files in the tests.

Comment: I think I found an answer to both my questions. The first one was a simple PHP error (I used `$obj.method()` instead of `$obj->method()`). The scond one is that it does not run if there is a parse error, which I found in the log.